# Engineering symbol miniscule sigma CHR$(229) prints on the screen but not to a file

Tags: basic, extended-ascii, qb64, quickbasic

PRINT CHR$(229) works fine

PRINT #1, CHR$(229) get an "a" with a small circle on top

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: Code Page 437 results in `σ` (U+03C3), but printing to a file means the file will be read in a system-specific character encoding, which may be something like Windows-1252 where `å` (U+00E5) is the result. I'm not sure if the [_MAPUNICODE statement](http://www.qb64.org/wiki/MAPUNICODE) works for files, so you might instead convert file output to UTF-8. You can use the [_MAPUNICODE function](http://www.qb64.org/wiki/MAPUNICODE_(function)) to get the Unicode code point of a character and convert that code point to UTF-8. For example, `CHR$(&hCF) + CHR$(&h83)` is the UTF-8 encoding for U+03C3 `σ`